# Form Script Not Sending Data

Tags: php, html, forms

I've created this html form and need the fields to send to my email address. It seems I don't have the PHP script correct, as it is not parsing the data over. I am presented with this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\www\mo\marinecforum\send_form_application.php on line 109 .

This is the html form code and php script (I am only allowed to post one hyperlink, sorry, but it's clear which is which): http://pastebin.com/Ruh7ZrLG

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bracket that isn't closed, I suspect.  Try using an editor with bracket matching to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Unless short_tags are enabled, the parser's probably complaining about the use of `<?` (instead of `<?php`). Thus it's not seeing final brace and knowing when to stop.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! That eliminated the error, however now upon hitting submit, the user is taken to the .php page. The confirmation doesn't show and the data is still not being sent to the designated $email_to address. So it seems the post action is behaving correctly, but something past that is not up to par. I apologize for such elementary questions, I am an intern at a non-profit with basic coding skills (as you can likely tell) and doing my best not to jump out of a window with this. Again, thank you.

Comment: I would first suggest removing the `@` in front of the email function. Let it dump out any trouble it's having rather than suppressing it. I would also output the value of `$email_message` and make sure it's valid and in correct format.